# Force keyword arguments in Haskell record init

Tags: haskell, initialization, record

Can I *force the use of keywords only* when initializing a record in Haskell?

```hs
data Person
   = Person
   {
       name :: String,
       idnum :: String
   }
   deriving( Show )


main = putStrLn $ show $ Person "oren" "9200"

-- I want to only allow such initializations:
-- main = putStrLn $ show $ Person { name = "moish", idnum = "7400" }
```

(This is especially useful when two fields have the same type)

Comment: [This post](https://www.haskellforall.com/2013/02/you-could-have-invented-comonads.html) on using comands to simulate object-oriented programming might be of interest. (Instead of using the record keywords, you would define additional functions to "extend" an in-progress person.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no.

Consider maybe the following solution?

```hs
newtype Name = Name String
newtype Idnum = Idnum String

data Person = Person { name :: Name, idnum :: Idnum }
```

Another possibility, worse in my opinion, is this:

```hs
module A (Person, name, idnum) where

data Person = Person
  { _name :: String
  , _idnum :: String
  }

name :: String -> (Person -> Person)
name n p = p { _name = n }

idnum :: String -> (Person -> Person)
idnum n p = p { _idnum = n }

emptyPerson :: Person
emptyPerson = Person "" ""

# in another module

module B

import A (Person, name, idnum)

myPerson = name "myname" . idnum "myidnum" $ emptyPerson
```

In this case there's no guarantee that both `name` and `idnum` get a value.

---

The fact that `Person` can always be used as a 'plain function' may turn out to be very useful. If you have, for instance, `getName :: IO String` and `getIdnum :: IO String`, then combining these to form a `getPerson :: IO Person` is concise: `getPerson = Person <$> getName <*> getIdnum`. This is only possible because we *don't* use record syntax here!

Comment: In the tradeoff between `newtype` "burden" and possible field order confusion - would you consider both options reasonable?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I don't think the newtype is really a burden - it's there specifically to make clients explicit about which field is which. I think the first approach would be by far the most popular. That said, there is something in the second approach: these functions like `name :: String -> (Person -> Person)` may be useful in other contexts as well as for avoiding field-order confusion. You could do both, if you wanted, by having `name` take a String and implicitly wrap it in the newtype needed to match the field's type.